# Proposal: tag for questions regarding the "europeanness" of features/conlangs

Tags: discussion, tags

Questions about the "europeanness" or "englishness" of a feature, structure or conlang in my experience relatively often come up in conlanging, particularly in the context of such features or structures being added unintentionally, usually due to the author not being familiar with alternative ways of doing things, and as such inadverdently copies peculiarities of their native language(s) (most commonly English); we just got [the first one](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/270/in-what-ways-are-well-known-a-priori-conlangs-inadvertently-eurocentric). As such I would like to propose the addition of a tag for this. The problem is what such a tag should be names. The most straightforward option would be something like [europeanness](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/europeanness) or [eurocentrism](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eurocentrism), but other options are also possible, such as [sae](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sae) (or [accidental-sae](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accidental-sae))(common abbreviation for [Standard Average European](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Average_European)). This is related to the topic of [relexification](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relexification) for which there already exists a tag, however it is not synonymous, as relexification can also be done of non-SAE languages, and conlangs that are overall not relexes may still unintentionally include some structures unintentionally copied from the native language(s) of the author?

Does adding a tag like this make sense, and if so what name for the tag is preferrable (which might not be any of my proposed names)?

Comment: English lacks four or five of the dozen defining SAE features listed in that WP article, so I'd prefer a broader term like “eurocentrism”.

Answer (score 5):

I agree that this would be an excellent idea -- I think that [eurocentrism](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eurocentrism) would be much better than [europeanness](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/europeanness) or [sae](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sae) because the word "europeanness" looks horrible and not everyone who visits will necessarily be familiar with the SAE abbreviation. Perhaps [sae](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sae) could be a synonym of [eurocentrism](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eurocentrism), though?

Comment: I'm not sure this would be needed, but if it is, eurocentrism is much better!